# How to help this avocado tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care, avocado

The tree lost a lot of it leaves over the last year and the upper parts seem to be dead wood by now. However it has sprouted a lot of new branches in the bottom portion as visible on the picture. The soil is probably not ideal (heavy clay), but it must have been standing here for a while judging by its size.

Is the tree even having a chance long term?

Will it help to trim the dead top portion?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The leaves and new branches seems spread irregularly (see on the left). This is strange. Did you had frost?

Comment: No frost - we are in southern California, so the lowest temperature last Winter was in the 40s (Fahrenheit).

Comment: added some more photos of strange spotty bark

Comment: i've seen frost in December in the mornings about 5 miles in from the coast, so frost is possible